# Working with Facebook Scrumptious app sample code

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use this code from the Facebook Scrumptious app sample code. I'm confused about the "your OG objects will have URLs hosted by your server." comment. Does this mean that I have to load a script on a server? If so, what script? Also, the "repeater.php" file. What is this?

Has anyone else had to configure this and would be able to point me in the right direction? thanks for any help.

```
    - (id<SCOGMeal>)mealObjectForMeal:(NSString*)meal 
{
    // This URL is specific to this sample, and can be used to
    // create arbitrary OG objects for this app; your OG objects
    // will have URLs hosted by your server.
    NSString *format =  
        @"https://<YOUR_BACK_END>/repeater.php?"
        @"fb:app_id=<YOUR_APP_ID>&og:type=%@&"
        @"og:title=%@&og:description=%%22%@%%22&"
        @"og:image=https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png&"
        @"body=%@";

    // We create an FBGraphObject object, but we can treat it as 
    // an SCOGMeal with typed properties, etc. See <FacebookSDK/FBGraphObject.h> 
    // for more details.
    id<SCOGMeal> result = (id<SCOGMeal>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];

    // Give it a URL that will echo back the name of the meal as its title, 
    // description, and body.
    result.url = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, 
                   @"<YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE>:meal", meal, meal, meal];

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Step 2 - Set Up Your Backend Server](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/#step2) in the tutorial. It includes a sample script and references to `repeater.php`. The code from your question appears further down the page in step 7.